Tikz plot in Quarto
I would like to use Quarto and Tikz to create both html and pdf outputs. For this, I am using the filter imagify which converts Tikz pictures for html outputs.
However, I do not get the same results depending on whether the image is stored in a tex file and then included in the Quarto file or directly coded in the Quarto file.
Here is a MWE showing the problem.
Quarto file, mwe.qmd:
---
title: "Test"
lang: en-GB
pdf-engine: lualatex
filters:
  - imagify
imagify:
  header-includes: |
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
    \usetikzlibrary{math}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
    \definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
    \definecolor{Classic_colour}{HTML}{2E77AB}
  pdf-engine: lualatex
format:
  html:
    toc: true
  pdf:
    fontsize: 12pt
    include-in-header:
      - text: |
          \usepackage[top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
          \usepackage{fontspec}
          \setmainfont{Gill Sans}
          \usepackage{tikz}
          \usetikzlibrary{positioning}
          \usetikzlibrary{calc}
          \usetikzlibrary{math}
          \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
          \usepackage{pgfplots}
          \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
          \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
          \definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
          \definecolor{Classic_colour}{HTML}{2E77AB}
---

Here is the figure (called Fig. F1) that I would like to put in a tex file. Note that it does not appear in the html output:

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [
        tick align = inside,
        domain = 0:2.5,
        samples = 200,
        no markers,
        smooth,
        clip = false,
        axis lines = left,
        ytick = \empty,
        xlabel = growth (in mm/yr),
        every axis plot/.append style={line width = 1pt, line join = round},
        legend style = {anchor = east},
    ]

    % Plot kind of lognormal curves (modified for the sake of readability)
    \addplot[dashed, color = black, domain = 0.301:2.5] {1/((x - 0.3) * sqrt(2*pi) * 0.65) * exp( -0.5 * (ln(x - 0.3) - 0)^2/0.65^2)}; % Shift the curve
    \addlegendentry{2000 - 2010}
    \addplot[name path = distrib_2050, color = black, domain = 0.0001:2.5] {1/(x * sqrt(2*pi) * 0.65) * exp( -0.5 * (ln(x) + 0.3)^2/0.5^2)};
    \addlegendentry{2041 - 2070}
        
    % Plot the median vertical line, forget plot to not add in the legend
    \addplot[forget plot, color = dkgreen] coordinates {(1.3, 0) (1.3, 0.6137574)}; % Lognormal 2000-2010 evaluated at 1.3
    \node[right] (medLabel) at (1.3, 0.6137574) {Current median};
    \fill[dkgreen] (medLabel.west) circle[radius = 2pt];
        
    % Define x axis path, used to fill between
    \path[name path = x_axis] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, 0) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}, 0);
 
    \addplot[Classic_colour, opacity = 0.5, area legend] fill between [of = distrib_2050 and x_axis, soft clip = {(1.3, 10) rectangle (4, 0)}];
    \addlegendentry{\( P(G > \mu_c) \)}

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

However, the Fig. F1 stored in a file appears in both outputs, html and pdf, but is not as expected (see in the pdf):

![Test axis environment figure](axisTest.tex){#fig-F1}


And the tex file, axisTest.tex:
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [
        tick align = inside,
        domain = 0:2.5,
        samples = 200,
        no markers,
        smooth,
        clip = false,
        axis lines = left,
        ytick = \empty,
        xlabel = growth (in mm/yr),
        every axis plot/.append style={line width = 1pt, line join = round},
        legend style = {anchor = east},
    ]

    % Plot kind of lognormal curves (modified for the sake of readability)
    \addplot[dashed, color = black, domain = 0.301:2.5] {1/((x - 0.3) * sqrt(2*pi) * 0.65) * exp( -0.5 * (ln(x - 0.3) - 0)^2/0.65^2)}; % Shift the curve
    \addlegendentry{2000 - 2010}
    \addplot[name path = distrib_2050, color = black, domain = 0.0001:2.5] {1/(x * sqrt(2*pi) * 0.65) * exp( -0.5 * (ln(x) + 0.3)^2/0.5^2)};
    \addlegendentry{2041 - 2070}
        
    % Plot the median vertical line, forget plot to not add in the legend
    \addplot[forget plot, color = dkgreen] coordinates {(1.3, 0) (1.3, 0.6137574)}; % Lognormal 2000-2010 evaluated at 1.3
    \node[right] (medLabel) at (1.3, 0.6137574) {Current median};
    \fill[dkgreen] (medLabel.west) circle[radius = 2pt];
        
    % Define x axis path, used to fill between
    \path[name path = x_axis] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, 0) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}, 0);
 
    \addplot[Classic_colour, opacity = 0.5, area legend] fill between [of = distrib_2050 and x_axis, soft clip = {(1.3, 10) rectangle (4, 0)}];
    \addlegendentry{\( P(G > \mu_c) \)}

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Finally, the command to render is quarto render mwe.qmd.
For information, I have MacTex 2024, with the last versions of dvisvgm, gs, etc...
This is the expected figure (first figure that I get in the pdf, does not appear in html):

and this is what I get in the html output (and also in the pdf, second picture)

Does anyone have an idea of what could be the problem?

Can you complete your code so people can reproduce? Help preparing a minimal working example to assist people helping you: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228.

Following the link from @cfr in the comments (tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) I built the MWE that could recreate the problem and actually found the solution!
Here is the MWE that still requires you to install the filter imagify:
---
title: "Test"
pdf-engine: lualatex
filters:
  - imagify
imagify:
  header-includes: |
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
  pdf-engine: lualatex
format:
  html:
    toc: true
  pdf:
    include-in-header:
      - text: |
          \usepackage{tikz}
          \usepackage{pgfplots}
          \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
          \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
---

Here is the figure (called Fig. F1) that I would like to put in a tex file. Note that it does not appear in the html output:

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [
        domain = 0:2.5,
        samples = 200,
        no markers,
        smooth,
        clip = false,
        axis lines = left,
        every axis plot/.append style={line width = 1pt, line join = round},
    ]

    \addplot[name path = logCurve, color = black, domain = 0.0001:2.5] {1/(x * sqrt(2*pi) * 0.5) * exp( -0.5 * (ln(x) + 0.3)^2/0.5^2)};
    \addplot[forget plot, color = blue] coordinates {(1.3, 0) (1.3, 0.5)};
    \node[right] (medLabel) at (1.3, 0.5) {Node should be at (1.3 , 0.5)};
    \fill[blue] (medLabel.west) circle[radius = 2pt];
        
    % Define x axis path, used to fill between
    \path[name path = x_axis] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, 0) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}, 0);
 
    \addplot[orange, opacity = 0.5, area legend] fill between [of = logCurve and x_axis, soft clip = {(1.3, 10) rectangle (4, 0)}];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

However, the Fig. F1 stored in a file appears in both outputs, html and pdf, but is not as expected (see in the pdf):

![Test axis environment figure](axisTest.tex){#fig-F1}

and the axisTest.tex which contains the figure:
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
    [
        domain = 0:2.5,
        samples = 200,
        no markers,
        smooth,
        clip = false,
        axis lines = left,
        every axis plot/.append style={line width = 1pt, line join = round},
    ]

    \addplot[name path = logCurve, color = black, domain = 0.0001:2.5] {1/(x * sqrt(2*pi) * 0.5) * exp( -0.5 * (ln(x) + 0.3)^2/0.5^2)};
    \addplot[forget plot, color = blue] coordinates {(1.3, 0) (1.3, 0.5)};
    \node[right] (medLabel) at (1.3, 0.5) {Node should be at (1.3 , 0.5)};
    \fill[blue] (medLabel.west) circle[radius = 2pt];
        
    % Define x axis path, used to fill between
    \path[name path = x_axis] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, 0) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax}, 0);
 
    \addplot[orange, opacity = 0.5, area legend] fill between [of = logCurve and x_axis, soft clip = {(1.3, 10) rectangle (4, 0)}];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

Now, the solution is to add \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18} in the imagify yaml part:
imagify:
  header-includes: |
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
  pdf-engine: lualatex

